# Using external source files (as a library) for imports in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm making a Java mod for Project Zomboid game (which is allowed by the license if you're one of those guys who post comments irrelevant to the question).

The game doesn't have the java classes packed in JAR, they're freely in the game sub-folders. I need to `import` some of the game classes into my classes. The Eclipse doesn't recognize the imports of course:

[image: image description]

I need to tell where should it look for the classes. I also decompiled whole game sources, so I can either use original compiled `.class` files or the `.java` sources. Using `.java` would be preferred. But I do not know how to tell Eclipse where to look for either.

During project setup, I told it to add library from external folder. This is the result in `.classpath` file of the project:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/.../ProjectZomboid/source" sourcepath="D:/.../ProjectZomboid/source">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.CLASSPATH_ATTR_LIBRARY_PATH_ENTRY" value="D:/.../ProjectZomboid"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

This is how it looks in the IDE:

[image: image description]

All packages appear to be empty.

Comment: Depending how your project is set-up you could try "properties of your project" -> "Java Build Path" -> tab "Libraries" -> "add external class folder". Select the directory where you have the subdirectory "zombie/...".

Comment: @SubOptimal thanks it works! :) I was also able to set Source directory for the binaries.